# Value of a character in C

Tags: c, string, character

I want to find out what the numeric, integer value of each character in C is, from A through Z is.

I would appreciate it if you can show me the code that finds out the value of each character in a string.

Thanks

Comment: Seems you want some functions from [`ctype.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

Comment: [Check here](http://www.asciitable.com) for the ascii values. For EBCDIC, [see the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)

Comment: This question would be *vastly* improved by some evidence of your attempts to solve it yourself. As written, the temptation to simply answer it with an ASCII chart and a generic warning about EBCDIC and possible mention of UTF-8 and even more arcane character sets and representations is pretty strong.

Comment: Ya sorry I realize that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is

```
char *s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
while(*s!='\0')
{
  printf("%c --> %d\n",*s,*s);
  s++;
}
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding any assumptions about character set and the order of the letters therein. Compatibility with EBCDIC may be relatively moot today, but much like the realization that integers are not required to be 2s complement, or floating point required to be binary, it bears keeping some awareness alive.

Comment: +1 for the same reason, I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: kk thanks for all answers

Comment: I thought putting the "A-Z" in that way, it would be easier for him to learn how things work, and easier to customize in his own way. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
char i;
for (i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
  printf("%c = %d\n", i, i);
```

Comment: [The same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644116/value-of-a-character-in-c#comment29167836_19644179) applies to this answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the requested code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char c;
  for(c='A';c<='Z';c++)
    printf("%c: %d\n",c,c);
}
```

Comment: ok so how would I also allow capital letters as well?

Comment: @user2817240 Excuse me but aren't `'A'` and `'Z'` capital letters?

Comment: If you mean small letters so you can simply exchange the capital letters with small letter in the code.

Comment: Also note that this will fail for any character encoding where letters are not organized in alphabetical order.

Comment: kk thanks for all answers

Comment: @H2CO3 - or if the encoding is not continuous

Comment: @mpez0 Yes, I meant that also by saying "not in alphabetical order".